How to get jq to output a long dataset?
Suppose I have this ndjson:
{"id": "one", "colors": [{"color": "blue"}, {"color": "red"}]}
{"id": "two", "colors": [{"color": "green"}]}

How do I get the output below?
one blue
one red
two green

Here is a failed attempt:
$ cat tmp/test.json  | jq -r '.id, .colors[].color'
one
blue
red
two
green

Here is a second failed attempt:
$ cat tmp/test.json  | jq -r '[.id, .colors[].color]|@tsv'
one blue    red
two green


The most direct approach:
jq -r '.id + " " + .colors[].color' my.ndjson

Since you mentioned @tsv, and since @tsv output has various potential advantages, you may also wish to consider:
.id as $id | .colors[] | [$id, .color] | @tsv

Or, as @oguz_ismail suggested, if you don't want to use as at all:
[.id]+(.colors[]|[.color])|@tsv


Very cool. How does this work?

The secret sauce is backtracking.

Is there a way to do your second script without assigning .id to $id, like in your first script ?

@Philippe - If you want an as-free solution, please see the update.

See https://jqplay.org/s/xz08aqy67G2 You don't need limit/repeat/transpose

Very nice. How do I learn enough about jq to be able to write things like this? I've read some of https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/, but it's still not obvious to me whether jq is its own language, or uses javascript with some sugar declared.

@dfrankow - jq is its own language.  I'd stick with the manual as much as possible, but you might like to check the wikipedia page on jq.  A recent introduction is https://medium.com/@buczynski.rafal/exploring-jq-a-guide-to-essential-techniques-and-tools-for-professionals-b9df9db490de; my attempt is at
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1i3ewUaOBrgt3uo9FcNuqCMbWJNfsdKNxrkiJEhsNSU4/edit#heading=h.8lgiwz1ywmon

The combinations function outputs all combinations of input elements. This will pair every id with every color:
$ jq -cr '[[.id], [.colors[].color]] | combinations' test.json
["one","blue"]
["one","red"]
["two","green"]

$ jq -r '[[.id], [.colors[].color]] | combinations | join(" ")' test.json
one blue
one red
two green


Came up with a version here too but had to chain a few calls of jq together to make it work too, just basically pulled the parts out into new JSON objects and then parsing those and joining similar to what answer @John Kugleman posted there too (maybe not as elegant :D).
cat test.json | jq '.[] | {"id": .id, "color": .colors[].color}' | jq -r '[.[]]|join(" ")'
output like:
one blue
one red
two green

